# How to build desktop applications with Apache Karaf/OSGi?

Tags: java, osgi, equinox, apache-felix, apache-karaf

Well im into building OSGi application for a [while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865301/how-to-create-a-maven-gemini-osgi-spring-project-into-eclipse), but i can't really find some tutorials which show the way to build Desktop Application ( in any languages ) with OSGi/Karaf.

I want to use karaf because it can then wrap Felix/Equinox. Most of Tutorials i found are about Enteprise Application(WEB). So is there any tutorials, which talk about building desktop application based on OSGi/Karaf?

Comment: I think there is nothing special about desktop applications. I created a Swing window simply in the start method of the activator of my bundle just like I can do it in my main method and it worked pretty well. I destroyed the window in the stop method of the activator.

Comment: Hi Balazs. This question inspired me and I started playing around with Swing in Karaf (for SWT pure Equinox is more natural approach). However no luck so far. Could you please paste the code you used?

Comment: Hi Balazs! Thx for ur comment... i'm also interested to see how u successful build such a desktop app! Thx

Comment: The most typical way of building a desktop application using OSGi is to use Eclipse RCP. I'm not sure how tightly it couples you to Equinox.

Comment: Why do you want to use Karaf?? It's a server platform, that's why you can only find tutorials about web apps. You'd be better off just using OSGi with either SWT, Swing or JavaFX.

Comment: Thx Neil Bartlett ... well i though it can be possible to use the capacity of Karaf to build Desktop Apps too. Do u know some Tutorials, teaching how to build SWT or Swing Apps with OSGi.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of a GUI application project that uses Apache karaf:

https://bitbucket.org/lorainelab/igb-fx

Using karaf to run a gui-based desktop application decreases development time. A developer makes a change to a bundle, builds the bundle, and then uses karaf shell commands to reload just that one bundle into the running application. There is no need to restart the entire application to view the effects of the new code. This is why were are using it.

We are using OSGi because we want greater modularity in the code base and because we want to support dynamically loaded "Apps" developed by 3rd party developers who write against our genome browser API.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the main intend right now for Karaf is to be used as a Server, though it still should be possible to start some guis on top. As your already familiar with building such bundles I'm sure you most probably could use just the minor version of Karaf and place your bundles in it. I have to admit I never done this before, so I'm not really sure about it.

Comment: Hi Achim! so there's no other way or tutorial to show how to build desktop App with OSGi?

Answer (score 0):

First of all OSGI is a component framework, it also leverages a feature missing in Java since its inception - runtime versioning. If you really need it (OSGI), it doesn't depend wether you develop a WEB or desktop application. In general I would recommend you to take a look at this documentation:
http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.2/deploy_osgi/Build-ModifyMaven.html
In that link you'll find how to convert an existing Maven project to bundle, check further chapters - there's info how-to deploy jars in e.g. Karaf (Karaf is an OSGI container)

Hope, this helps